# Erro ao clicar no button para salvar dados no banco

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

Bom dia galera, estou tentando salvar alguns dados no banco de dados, por um `button` do *windows form C#* e aparece este erro. Já tentei de tudo mas o erro persiste. Fiz o print e colei o código do forms e do sql, por favor, alguém poderia me ajudar?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
strSql ="insert into Paciente 
         values(@IDPACIENTE,@NOMEPACIENTE,@SOBRENOME,@DATANASCIMENTO,
                @GENERO,@CPF,@UFRG,@EMAIL,@CELULAR,@TELEFONEFIXO,
                @PRONTUARIO,@CONVENIO,@CARTEIRINHACONVENIO,@VALIDADECARTEIRINHA)";

sqlCon = new SqlConnection(strCon);
SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand(strSql, sqlCon);

comando.Parameters.Add("@IDPACIENTE", SqlDbType.Int).Value = textBox_ID.Text;
comando.Parameters.Add("@NOMEPACIENTE", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox_Nome.Text;
comando.Parameters.Add("@SOBRENOME", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox_SOBRENOME.Text;
comando.Parameters.Add("@DATANASCIMENTO", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = maskedTextBox_DataNascimento.Text;
comando.Parameters.Add("@GENERO", SqlDbType.Char).Value =comboBox_Genero.Text;
comando.Parameters.Add("@CPF", SqlDbType.Char).Value =maskedTextBox_CPF.Text;
comando.Parameters.Add("@UFRG", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox_UFRG.Text;
comando.Parameters.Add("@EMAIL", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value =textBox_EMAIL.Text;
comando.Parameters.Add("@CELULAR", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value =maskedTextBox_CELULAR.Text;
comando.Parameters.Add("@TELEFONEFIXO", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value =maskedTextBox_TELEFONE.Text;
comando.Parameters.Add("@PRONTUARIO", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value =textBox_Prontuario.Text;
comando.Parameters.Add("@CONVENIO", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value =textBox_CONVENIO.Text;
comando.Parameters.Add("@CARTEIRINHACONVENIO", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value =textBox_CarteirinhaConvenio.Text;
comando.Parameters.Add("@VALIDADECARTEIRINHA", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value =maskedTextBox_ValidadeCarteirinha.Text;

try
{
    sqlCon.Open();
    comando.ExecuteNonQuery();
    MessageBox.Show("Cadastro Efetuado Com Sucesso");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    
}
finally
{
    sqlCon.Close();
```

---

```
CREATE TABLE Paciente(
    IDPACIENTE INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    NOMEPACIENTE VARCHAR (50),
    SOBRENOME  VARCHAR (50),
    DATANASCIMENTO DATETIME,
    GENERO CHAR(1),
    CPF CHAR(12) NOT NULL,
    UFRG  VARCHAR (50),
    EMAIL VARCHAR (100),
    CELULAR VARCHAR (100),
    TELEFONEFIXO VARCHAR(10),
    PRONTUARIO VARCHAR(100),
    CONVENIO VARCHAR(100),
    CARTEIRINHACONVENIO VARCHAR(100),
    VALIDADECARTERINHA  DATETIME
)
```

Comment: o erro diz que não pode converter implicitamente uma string em data: no formulário, ele é string, no banco, é data. Você precisa converter em data antes de salvar, ou mudar no banco (*não indicado*).

Answer (score 0):

Voce precisa converter o texto da sua maskedTextBox em DateTime, pois a coluna `VALIDADECARTERINHA` do seu banco de dados é do tipo DateTime e voce está tentando passar uma string para esse campo.

Tente trocar esta linha:

`comando.Parameters.Add("@VALIDADECARTEIRINHA", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value =maskedTextBox_ValidadeCarteirinha.Text;`

Por esta:

`comando.Parameters.Add("@VALIDADECARTEIRINHA", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = Convert.ToDateTime(maskedTextBox_ValidadeCarteirinha.Text);`

Answer (score 0):

Voce pode usar como o comentario que fizeram, ou dessa forma que eu vou mostrar, porque pode acontecer do conteudo da string não ser uma data válida, então evitar erros é uma boa prática:

```
string str = "2021-05-10";
DateTime result;
if(DateTime.TryParse(str, out result)) //retorna true se conseguir converter para DateTime                 
{                     
//usar o conteudo da variável result                 
}
```